# Rails - how to get all manufactures from a product category?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

I have `Category` model, where are placed products. Each product belongs to manufacturer (there are also products, which have not set manufacturer - these ones I would like to mark as "Unknown").

Here are my models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :category
end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :products
end
```

This is a simple query, how I get products from respective category:

```
@products = @category.products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

I would like to print all manufacturers, which have products in the respective category... I am struggling with this part half a day and still can't find the query...

Could you help me, please, with this part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Category model:

```
has_many :manufacturers, :through => :products
```

Then you can call

```
@category.manufacturers
```

Check out the documentation of [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for more on the `through` option.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Manufacturer.where(id: @category.products.map(&:manufacturer_id).uniq)
```

Or we can rely on the database in fetching unique values, which should be faster on big tables:

```
Manufacturer.where(id: Product.select("DISTINCT manufacturer_id").
  where(category: @category).map(&:manufacturer_id))
```

And we can simplify this by using `pluck` method in rails >= 3.2.1:

```
Manufacturer.where(id: Product.uniq.where(category_id: @category.id).
  pluck(:manufacturer_id))
```

---

Also I want to add that `has_many :manufacturers, :through => :products` solution can be a bit slower on big data because of the joining (in my experience).

Comment: thanks! Just trying it to integrate, but I am facing with this problem: `undefined method "where" for #<Array:0x00000142973bd0>`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, try again please with the last.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and instead of error above I got `PG::Error: ERROR:  column products.category does not exist`. But the column `category_id` exist in the `products` table

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that new database on hand. Now it should works.